# Sufficient condition on coefficients for a complex power series to be bounded

Tags: cv.complex-variables, power-series

Let $f(z)$ be an entire function (on $\mathbb{C}$). Assume it has a power series of the form 
$$\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^nc_{2n}z^{2n},$$ 
where $c_{2n}\geq 0$ for all $n$.

Is there a sufficient condition on the coefficients $c_{2n}$ under which the sum is bounded for all $z=x\in \mathbb{R}?$

Comment: If $c_n=\frac{1}{n!}$ then the series is bounded on the real line. But I guess this is not the answer you had in mind, so you might as well be a little bit more precise in your question.

Comment: I am tempted to believe there is no simple criterion which would let us decide this. For example, note that if your series is bounded on the real line, then chainging a single $c_{2n}$ by any amount will lead to a function unbounded on $\mathbb R$. This tells us, for example, that any such condition has to take into account _all_ coefficients, not just the ones with sufficiently large powers of $x$.

Comment: I also would say there hardly exists any suitable criterion. Notice that there are many such functions, including $\cos ax$, $\frac{\sin ax}x$, $\frac1x\int_0^x\frac{\sin at}t\,dt$, etc., and also their linear combinations with nonnegative coefficients --- possibly with infinite number of terms.

Comment: Putting together the comments above  we may say, slightly more generally: If $\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_{2n}x^{2n}$ is such a series:   **(i)** any finite subset of coefficients with positive indices is  uniquely determined by all the others, because any perturbation of it changes the series by a polynomial, thus unbounded; **(ii)**  for any $p$,  the coefficients $c_{2n}$ corresponding to indices $n$ multiples of $2p+1$ are *not*   determined by all the others, because one may add e.g. the series of $\cos x^{2p+1}$.

Comment: and I think, many other subsets $S\subset\mathbb{N}$  may be the support of a family of coefficients $c_{2n}$ satisfying the condition; so a first question could be: characterize these $S$.

Comment: $\frac{a_{2n+2}}{a_{2n}}\rightarrow0$, just due to convergence on $\mathbb{R}$. A necessary condition.

Comment: @T. Amdeberhan actually the quotient $c_{2n+2}/c_{2n}$ may be unbounded; consider $\cos(x)+\cos(x^3)$

Comment: Please see my similar question and the comments there: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/27100/criteria-for-boundedness-of-power-series