# When is entire function bounded on a ray?

Tags: cv.complex-variables

Let $f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n z^n$ be entire function on the complex plane. May we express the property $\int_0^\infty |f(x)|^2 /x dx<\infty$ or some other property controlling the behavior for large positive $x$ in terms of coefficients? This property is quite rare:if we change finitely many coefficients arbitrarily, it no longer holds.
To be more specific: for given sequence $(a_n) $, can we find all good sequences $(c_n) $ for which $(a_n c_n) $ is also good? Generically, how many such pairs of good sequences do we have?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "a good sequence"? As for the question in the title, the following thread in MO might be relevant: https://mathoverflow.net/a/29735/1593

Comment: A similar question was asked here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/27100/criteria-for-boundedness-of-power-series

Comment: Also see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/321550/when-is-entire-function-bounded-on-a-ray/321620#321620